# Adding mailchimp list subscribers(users list) in wordpress admin dashboard

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I have mailchimp account where user subscribers list generated after filling mailchimp form in my wordpress site.

Now i want to add the subscriber user list to add in my wordpress admin dashboard.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Mailchimp integration with Wordpress -

There are several plugins that can help you out in integration of WordPress and Mailchimp as - [Integral MailChimp for WordPress](http://integralwp.com/plugins/complete-mailchimp-plugin-for-wordpress/) (related help can be found here - [HELP](https://connect.mailchimp.com/how-to/133))
OR you can try [MailChimp for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/)

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: i already have mailchimp plugin installed but when a user fill registration form the record store in mailchimp official website in the form of rows , now if admin want to see the subscriber list he will visit http://mailchimp.com/ to see the list , is there any way to get the subscriber list from mailchimp official site and show it on wordpress admin dashboard